# Pairing of elements

Tags: permutations, combinations, multisets

Suppose I have two lists (not sure that's the right word), each with $N$ not necessarily distinct elements. In how many ways can I make distinct pairings of the two lists?

**Example**

I have the lists $(A, A, A, B, C)$ and $(A, D, D, E, E)$. A few of the distinct pairings I could form would be

$(AA, AD, AD, BE, CE)$

$(AA, AD, AE, BD, CE)$

$(AA, AD, AE, BE, CD)$

But how many pairings are there in total?

I have a feeling the answer is obvious, I'm just not seeing it at the moment.

**Edit**

After some more googling I found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67359/the-number-of-pairings-between-multisets) page which suggests the solution isn't obvious at all.

Can anyone confirm the answer given there is correct?

Comment: The answer you  link to is correct. Note: if one of the sets has no repetitions then the question has a standard easy answer. It's $n!/a!b!.\cdots z!$ where the factorials in the denominator count repetitions.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker: Thanks. But what a bugger! I suspected an easy answer I just wasn't seeing.